# Netsuite: Basic Search of SalesOrders returns orders whose ItemList.Item[i].Item.Type is always missing

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I am using SuiteTalk to perform a basic search for Sales Orders

I can get orders just fine, each order comes with an `itemList`  However, all items in `itemList` are missing `RecordRef type`.  It's not even null.  Just. Missing.

(Here's [NetSuite documentation](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/schema/other/recordref.html?mode=package) showing that it should be part of the object)

I expect some items should be `type = RecordRef.kitItem`.  And others should be `type = RecordRef.inventoryItem`

How do I ensure that all items have a RecordRef type?
Is there some permission I need to enable on my token?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in your `itemList` are objects of type [`SalesOrderItem`](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/schema/other/salesorderitem.html), and do not have a `Type` property. In order to get the `Type` of a `SalesOrderItem`, you will have to perform an additional search. Below is an advanced search that I wrote to retrieve the `Type` of an item, given its internal id.

```
ItemSearchAdvanced customSearch = new ItemSearchAdvanced()
{
    columns = new ItemSearchRow()
    {
        basic = new ItemSearchRowBasic()
        {
           type = new SearchColumnEnumSelectField[] { new SearchColumnEnumSelectField() },
        }
    },

    criteria = new ItemSearch()
    {
        basic = new ItemSearchBasic()
        {
            internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField
            {
                @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                operatorSpecified = true,
                searchValue = new RecordRef[] { new RecordRef { internalId = itemInternalId } };
            }
        }
    }
};

Client.Service.searchPreferences.returnSearchColumns = true;
SearchResult res = Client.Service.search(customSearch);
ItemSearchRow row = (ItemSearchRow)res?.searchRowList?[0];
return row?.basic?.type?[0].searchValue;
```

Comment: Man, given how tightly NetSuite controls "concurrent connections" it would sure be nice if they gave an option for more data returned in their higher level search calls.